# Using x- for Custom Log Information with AWS C# SDK for S3

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to pass some additional contextual information on a GET request to S3 for logging purposes.

According to the Custom Log Information section on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LogFormat.html I should just be able to add some additional querystring values to the Key.

This however doesn't work and I get a "The specified key does not exist." error back from AWS.

I'm using the AWS SDK for C#

And constructing my request like so:

```
var request = new GetObjectRequest()
{
  BucketName = "MyBucket",
  Key = "myitem.png?x-uid=1&x-oid=1"                        
};
```

And dispatching using the AmazonS3Client.

Should this be possible? Is there an alternative way of sending the request? I will also need to do the same on POST/PUT/DELETE requests as well.

Comment: Not the key.  *You can include custom information to be stored in the access log record for a request by adding a custom query-string parameter to the URL for the request.*  URL != key.  Doing what you're doing is going to urlencode those extra characters so that S3 thinks they're part of the actual key, so the error message here is correct.  How to convince the SDK to let you add actual query-string parameters to the request is what you need to find and it's not obvious, from the docs, how to do that.

Comment: Fair point on URL != Key, but no other obvious way to attempt to attach the desired query parameters. Will try and dig further through the Clients source to see it's possible.